# Regular expression for parsing postal address?

Tags: c#-4.0

Hello i'm new to programming.I have address in following format and i want to separate house number and street number portion.

```
house no.966 s# 70  Kashmir road Peshawar road Rawalpindi
house no.970 st. # 43  Darian Kalar saeedan
H# 110 Street No.35  Dhowk kala Rwp
h# 124 Street No.73  G-11/3 ISB
h no.423 St. No.23  Chan chirag Rawat
H No.437 st. # 61  Chaklal scheme 3 RAWALPINDI
```

Any help suggestion on this ?

Comment: From my understanding, you want to separate like no.966  <-- house number    st. # 43   <--- street number. Is it correct?

Comment: If you're new to programming, why did you throw yourself in at the deep(er) end? Begin learning the language from, well, the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're just after the two sets of digits in the order they occur, so you can just do this:

```
void Main()
{
    var addresses = new string[] { 
        "house no.966 s# 70  Kashmir road Peshawar road Rawalpindi",
        "house no.970 st. # 43  Darian Kalar saeedan",
        "H# 110 Street No.35  Dhowk kala Rwp",
        "h# 124 Street No.73  G-11/3 ISB",
        "h no.423 St. No.23  Chan chirag Rawat",
        "H No.437 st. # 61  Chaklal scheme 3 RAWALPINDI"
    };

    Regex houseAndStreet = new Regex(@"(\d+).+?(\d+)");

    foreach (string address in addresses)
    {
        Match match = houseAndStreet.Match(address);
        string house = match.Groups[1].Value;
        string street = match.Groups[2].Value;
        Console.WriteLine ("House = {0}, Street = {1}", house, street);
    }
}
```

You'd want to add some error checking to make it more robust, but that's the basic idea.

The regular expression breaks down like this:

- `(\d+)` one or more digits in a group
- `.+?` a non-greedy search for any other characters
- `(\d+)` one or more digits in another group

Comment: Actuall i want whole string from start to street number.

Comment: In that case you want `match.Groups[0]`. But I would have thought the raw numbers would be more useful.